# Extract any first two letters and 6 digit number from an excel and copy it to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I extract only the first two letters and the 6 digit number from one cell to another?  ie.  Column 1 will have aa111111, bb222222, ccccc, dd12, eeee1

I only want to copy aa111111 and bb222222 in this case.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
    Dim s As String

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1

    For i = 1 To N
        s = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Len(s) = 8 _
            And Mid(s, 1, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z]" _
            And Mid(s, 2, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z]" _
            And IsNumeric(Mid(s, 3)) Then
                Cells(K, 2).Value = s
                K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are in A:A then in B1 (and copy down):

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>7,IF(AND(CODE(LOWER(MID(A1,{1,2},1)))<>CODE(UPPER(MID(A1,{1,2},1))),ISNUMBER(MID(A1,{3;4;5;6;7;8},1)*1)),LEFT(A1,8),""),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with ctrl + shift + enter.

Running evaluate formula shows what happens and how it works :)

---

Using VBA then this will do:

```
Sub CopyMe()
  Dim x As Variant, i As Long
  For Each x In Range([A1], Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
    If x Like "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]######" Then
      i = i + 1
      Cells(i, 2) = x
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it. The formula loops through your string looking for a 6 digit number, at which point it takes the previous two characters (as long as they exist) and returns the 8 character string. Otherwise it returns an empty string.

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SUMPRODUCT(ROW($A$1:$A$100),--ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:$A$100),6))))-2,8),"")
```

*Loops 100 times, so will work with strings up to a maximum length of 106 characters*. To use the formula place your string in column **A**, and place this formula in cell **B1** (for example) and drag down